# How to repair my ethernet connection?

Tags: debian

I do not have any WiFi issues, only problems with the local ethernet network. Laptop's Acer Predator GX-792.

Debian constantly tries to connect to the Synology NAS DS213 with no avail. So I usually stop the connection to avoid incessant notifications.

When I type :

```
sudo isenkram-autoinstall-firmware
```

I get :

```
info: some kernel driver requested extra firmware files: ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware-4.bin ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin ath10k/QCA9887/hw1.0/board-2.bin ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/board-2.bin ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-2.bin ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-3.bin rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin rtl_bt/rtl8723bs_config.bin rtl_bt/rtl8723ds_config.bin rtl_bt/rtl8723ds_fw.bin rtl_bt/rtl8761a_config.bin\
info: locating packages with the requested firmware files\
info: determining whether enabling other components is required\
info: No new firmware package with requested firmware detected.
```

But... Impossible to find those packages anywhere...
It's always another version of the firmware.
I'm using a fresh version of Debian 11.

**EDIT**
My `lspci` output :

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 05) 00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6th-10th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 05)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Thermal Subsystem (rev 31)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev f1)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM175 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Power Management Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation CM238 HD Audio Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family SMBus (rev 31)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP104BM [GeForce GTX 1080 Mobile] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
```

My `sudo grep alx /var/log/syslog` shows :

```
2023-03-20T09:07:07.185167+01:00 PortableLionelP kernel: [    2.108956] alx 0000:03:00.0 eth0: Qualcomm Atheros AR816x/AR817x Ethernet [d4:5d:df:07:eb:35]
2023-03-20T09:07:07.185174+01:00 PortableLionelP kernel: [    2.265550] alx 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: renamed from eth0 
2023-03-20T09:07:07.342845+01:00 PortableLionelP kernel: [    7.515731] alx 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: NIC Up: 1 Gbps Full 
2023-03-21T09:16:48.247499+01:00 PortableLionelP kernel: [    2.093693] alx 0000:03:00.0 eth0: Qualcomm Atheros AR816x/AR817x Ethernet [d4:5d:df:07:eb:35]
2023-03-21T09:16:48.247508+01:00 PortableLionelP kernel: [    2.250029] alx 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: renamed from eth0 
2023-03-21T09:16:48.420862+01:00 PortableLionelP kernel: [    7.598653] alx 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: NIC Up: 1 Gbps Full 
2023-03-22T09:48:58.975491+01:00 PortableLionelP kernel: [    2.094439] alx 0000:03:00.0 eth0: Qualcomm Atheros AR816x/AR817x Ethernet [d4:5d:df:07:eb:35] 
2023-03-22T09:48:58.975504+01:00 PortableLionelP kernel: [    2.241806] alx 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: renamed from eth0 
2023-03-22T09:48:59.183635+01:00 PortableLionelP kernel: [    7.354977] alx 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: NIC Up: 1 Gbps Full 
2023-03-22T11:01:06.533832+01:00 PortableLionelP kernel: [ 4333.778943] alx 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Link Down 
2023-03-22T11:01:09.241909+01:00 PortableLionelP kernel: [ 4336.487596] alx 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: NIC Up: 1 Gbps Full
```

`ip link` includes this:

```
enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d4:5d:df:07:eb:35 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Debian always says "La configuration IP n'était disponible" (IP configuration isn't available).

Both Ethernet and Wi-Fi are on the same router and disabling Wi-Fi does not solve the connection problem. I do not see the NAS in Discover nor in the Synology Assistant. I am using internet via WiFi, not through LAN.

There are no intermediaries between the NAS and my computer as the NAS is directly plugged to my computer.

Last findings, using Windows I see the NAS. It has an IP of 169.254.60.41 and is "pingable" but when I use Debian the same IP is unreachable. Moreover, the NAS Synology led is blinking (orange). So there must be an installation problem I think. I will investigate that. I still do not know why Debian cannot see the NAS and Windows can.

Comment: Just because some software lists a gazillion firmware files for lots of different hardware does not mean you need any of them. Not sure how the Synology NAS is involved either. // The first step should be to use `lspci` or a similar tool to find out what Ethernet controller you have, exactly. Then you can investigate the drivers and firmware you may need.

Comment: For me, it is not just a random list. It says that they are "requested", that's why I put that here. Maybe this is not relevant but I do not have any other clues so...
I will edit my question to give you the `lspci` output.

Comment: Yes, they are in the list because the kernel modules exist. On all Debian machines. Your hardware doesn’t use them though. // So you have a Killer E2400 NIC. That’s the only thing you need to focus on. // First, you should find out if you actually do have a problem (does the device appear on `ip link`? does it connect? does DHCP work?) and then describe the problem in as much detail as possible.

Comment: `ip link` includes this
> enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d4:5d:df:07:eb:35 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
Debian always says "La configuration IP n'était disponible".
Yes, I have an Acer, an Acer Predator GX-792.

Comment: Both are on the same router and disabling WiFi does not solve the connection problem.
I do not see the NAS in Discover nor in the Synology Assistant

Comment: Search for `firmware-atheros` package (non-free)

Comment: I already have installed that package via `sudo apt-get install`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether the NAS has a default IP or if it uses DHCP. I checked the [manual](https://global.download.synology.com/download/Document/Hardware/HIG/DiskStation/13-year/DS213/enu/Syno_QIG_2bay_enu.pdf) of DS213, nothing there.

It does state that as the first step you need to install DSM using the web browser. However your `enp3s0` doesn't have an IP address, so there's no way to connect. Also the NAS won't have internet access connected to your LAN port, so installing DSM is impossible.

Ensure DHCP is enabled on your router and connect the NAS there. Wait a few moments, open your browser and go to `https://find.synology.com`. As per the manual you should now be able to reach the Web Assistant and install DSM. After this Synology Assistant should work.

If you can't reach it, check the router's web interface to find whether the NAS has connected and has an IP. If yes, you should reach the Web Assistant at `https://<IP address>`.

If you get connectivity problems after connecting the NAS to the router, there may be an IP address conflict. According to Synology resources some devices use default IP `192.168.1.1/24`, which clashes with 99% of all SoHo market routers. To fix that disconnect the NAS, reconnect to the router's web interface, change its IP to `192.168.1.2/24` and try again.

This assumes that your router's running with the usual settings, where default IP range is `192.168.1.0/24`.